# convert Google Rss feed into Yahoo Rss Feed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, rss

### convert Google RSS feed into Yahoo RSS Feed

I find myself working with feeds (RSS, atom, JSON, etc) pretty often, and most of the time it's mixing these feeds together for a site, and it's nothing but pain trying to build your code to get every condition right, and it's a waste of time, money and resources.

Can someone tell me if this code has a syntax error because I run nothing output:

```
(function($){

var rss = function($el, url, options){
    var s = this;
    s.el = $el;
    s.opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.feeds.defaults, options );
    s.query = encodeURIComponent(url);
    s.load();
}

rss.prototype = {
    output : "",
    constructor : rss,
    delay: 50,
    timer : null,
    
    load : function( query ){
        var s = this,
            q = query || s.query,
            //(google api)
            //uri = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=" + s.opts.num + "&output=" + s.opts.output + '&q=' + q + '&callback=?';

             //(yahoo api)
              uri = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=" + "select*from rss where url=" + q + '&format=' + s.opts.format + '&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=?';


if ( !s.timer ) {
            s.timer = setTimeout( function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: uri,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        s.output = s.display( data );
                        s.timer = null;
                    }
                });
            }, s.delay );
        }
    },
    display : function (data) {
        var sHtml ="", s = this;
        if ( !data.responseData.feed ) {
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Of course it has syntax errors, you didn't close the curlybrace of `rss.prototype` and also the braces of the outer closure. Please use a Text Editor that understands Javascript in the future, such as `Atom` or `Visual Studio Code`, which will display these kinds of trivial errors to you.

Comment: im just sent half of my code, I have tried every combination of query I can think of seem does not working. please advices me. 
              uri = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=" + "select*from rss where url=" + q + '&format=' + s.opts.format + '&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=?';

Comment: @failengineer what is the error/response of YQL? I had a query to a website using a similar approach of yours, but the result was something like `datatables not available`...[edit] your question.